# How to configure Squirrel SQL client to work with MS Access

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess, squirrel-sql

I'm struggling to get Squirrel SQL to connect to MS Access database (just a normal one, no password):

- I create an Alias and use Driver: JBDC ODBC bridge (There is a tick in front of this driver)
- I don't know what to put in URL
- -------- I use: Path to database file ~~> Unsuccessful
- -------- I use: jdbc:odbc:Path to database file ~~> Unsuccessful
- I'm running it on windows 7.

I guest this should be a simple straight forward process, but please advise me how to get it working.

Answer (score 9):

Now that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 the previous answer to this question will become less relevant over time. The following method uses the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver so it will work with Java 8 and it will also work on non-Windows platforms.

First, make sure that you are using UCanAccess version **3.0.5** or later. Download the latest version of the UCanAccess driver (`bin.zip` file) and unzip it to a convenient location. For this example I unzipped it to

```
/home/gord/Downloads/JDBC/UCanAccess
```

[image: uca305folder.png]

**Note:** When unzipping the distribution file be sure to specify "Keep directory structure" (or similar, depending on your unzip tool) so the folder structure appears as in the screenshot above.

### Creating a Squirrel SQL "Driver" entry (one-time setup)

In Squirrel SQL, create a new "Driver" entry for UCanAccess

[image: SquirrelDriver1]

and specify the location of **loader/ucanload.jar** on the "Extra Class Path" pane

[image: SquirrelDriver2]

**Note:** Remember to enter `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanloadDriver` as the "Class Name" (see above).

### Creating a database "Alias" (one for each database)

To open a specific database, create a Squirrel SQL "Alias" entry, replacing the `<path_to_database_file>` placeholder with the actual path to the file

[image: SquirrelAlias]

or, in Windows

[image: WindowsAlias.png]

**Important:** Make sure that the connection URL ends with `;showSchema=true`.

Comment: On Windows 10 with SQuirrel 3.9.1 and UCanAccess 4.0.4 I had to add a command line parameter in the SQuirreL launcher batch file (`squirrel-sql.bat`) on the line that begins with `start`:  `-DUCANACCESS_HOME=\path\to\ucanaccess\UCanAccess-4.0.4-bin`

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Put below string in URL:

*(Assuming that path to your database file is D:\DBs\DatabaseFile.mdb)*

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=D:\DBs\DatabaseFile.mdb
```