# SQuirrel and UCanAccess

Tags: ucanaccess, squirrel-sql

I am trying to configure SQuirrel to work with UCanAccess and get the following error: The UCANACCESS_HOME system variable isn't defined: it should be: -DUCANACCESS_HOME=  I defined the variable as a system variable but it does not work

[image]

Comment: Since you are using a version of UCanAccess newer than 3.0.5 you shouldn't need to set the `UCANACCESS_HOME` Java system variable. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36608661/2144390) on how to configure it. Note that you need to preserve the folder structure when you unzip the bin.zip file.