# Squirrel SQL - UCANACCESS_HOME system variable isn't defined

Tags: ucanaccess, squirrel-sql

**Setup**

- Windows 10 1709, 16299.64
- Squirrel SQL  squirrel-sql-3.8.0
  installed at "C:\Program Files\squirrel-sql-3.8.0"
- UCanAccess  UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin installed at "C:\Java\UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin"
- Java 8 Update 151

I'm new to Squirrel SQL.  I'm trying to setup Squirrel SQL with UCanAccess to use use it on an Access accdb.  I followed Gord Thompson's posting at
[How to configure Squirrel SQL client to work with MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390609/how-to-configure-squirrel-sql-client-to-work-with-ms-access).  Squirrel has a UCanAccess driver setup so all you need to do is point it to a UCanAccess jar file.  Pics posted OneDrive.  No need to sign in.  Just click view at bottom form.

[Squirrel Driver Setup](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Au_kkFZUk72orQd3BkfvE4MfAtfW)

Next, I setup an [Alias](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Au_kkFZUk72orQg2hA55pS9ZEiwN)

I tried to connect to database and I get an 
[error](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Au_kkFZUk72orQk-x3KolMx0-iyJ)

```
java.sql.SQLException: The UCANACCESS_HOME system variable isn't defined:
  it should be:
-DUCANACCESS_HOME=<your path to the UCanAccess-3.x.x-bin folder>
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanloadDriver.noHome(UcanloadDriver.java:96)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanloadDriver.<clinit>(UcanloadDriver.java:59)
```

I searched for a solution and tried various things without success.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Extra Class Path" tab you need to be pointing to `loader/ucanload.jar`, not the main ucanaccess*.jar.